# Recursive Search in T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a table which links a Position to a Position.  It’s the manager relationship.

So we would have.

```
Position| Line Manager
-----------------------------------
Job 1   | Job 3
Job 2   | Job 3
Job 3   | Job 8
Job 4   | Job 6
Job 5   | Job 6
Job 6   | Job 4
Job 7   | Job 4
Job 8   | Job 9
Job 9   | Job 10
Job 10  | NULL
```

So what I am looking for is a query that when Line Manager = job 8 it shows Job 3, Job 2, and Job 1.

When  you look up Job 8, it see’s Job 3 is the position ‘underneath’ it, then it looks up to see who Job 3 is the line manager for, and, then looks up to see what those jobs are the line manager for, and so on until it hits the end of the chain.

I would then link those jobs to people to pull up details.  So it goes down the work hierarchy, showing not just everyone directly under then, but all the people directly below them too, and so on.

I’m making a dogs dinner of explaining it, and I’m not having a great deal of luck with Google.  Is this kind of recursive search viable in SQL?

Thanks for any help or pointers!

Comment: Try searching for `recursive CTE` (Common Table Expression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a CTE, something like this:

```
with  CTE as 
        (
select  Position, LineManager
from    Positions
where   LineManager = 8        
union all      
select  child.Position,child.LineManager 
from    Positions child
join 
CTE parent on child.LineManager = parent.Position
)
select  * from    CTE
```

Comment: That's great, seems to do exactly what I want.  Thanks!